# How to get a clean message after using the sudo apt update in ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I wanna remove all these error and get back to a clean message. But I don't know how to remove these.

```
sudo apt update

    Hit:1 http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code stable InRelease                
    Hit:2 http://ppa.launchpad.net/linuxuprising/java/ubuntu focal InRelease       
    Hit:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease                         
    Ign:4 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu focal InRelease         
    Hit:5 https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                  
    Hit:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease                 
    Hit:7 https://download.sublimetext.com apt/stable/ InRelease                   
    Get:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease [101 kB]      
    Err:9 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu focal Release
      404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1560:8008::19 80]
    Get:10 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease [114 kB]
    Reading package lists... Done       
    E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu focal Release' does not have a Release file.
    N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
    N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Answer (score 0):

The key to the real problem can be found on this line - `E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu focal Release' does not have a Release file.`

You need to clean the PPA to get rid of the error. Thankfully, someone explained how to do that, here - https://askubuntu.com/questions/866901/what-can-i-do-if-a-repository-ppa-does-not-have-a-release-file

Comment: That link was helpfull, now I got rid of the error. Thank you.

Comment: I am having problem with wireless connection. When I was using windows 7 then the wifi connection was working fine but I install Ubuntu removing the windows, now wifi is not working. There is no symbol for wifi in the to right corner where the other symbols apear. Now I am using usb thetering to connect to the internet. I think I don't have a driver for the wirless device but I don't know how to install the driver for that device. I have tried to install driver for that but still got no good result.

Comment: Network:
  Device-1: Realtek RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet 
  driver: r8169 
  IF: enp1s0 state: down mac: 9c:5a:44:06:8e:ac 
  Device-2: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter 
  driver: N/A 
  Device-3: Qualcomm Atheros type: USB driver: btusb 
  IF-ID-1: usb0 state: unknown speed: N/A duplex: N/A mac: 0a:7e:82:17:08:33